# select ancestor node by attribute with Xpath in Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath

My XML is conceptually in this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
 <Employee>
    <age>40</age>
    <name lang="en">Tom</name>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <role>Manager</role>
 </Employee>
 <Employee>
    <age>25</age>
    <name lang="fr">Meghna</name>
    <gender>Female</gender>
    <role>Manager</role>
 </Employee>
</Employees>
```

now, what I want is to select all the employees who have name with lang="en", and write them to a new XML file.

So in this example I want just the first employee:

```
<Employee>
    <age>40</age>
    <name lang="en">Tom</name>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <role>Manager</role>
</Employee>
```

I tried to do something like that

```
//Employee[//name[@lang='en']]
```

(I am deliberately using // before name, since name doesn't have to be a direct child of Employee)

I don't know how to write it to a file, and for some reason - my query doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2):

According to the XML posted, you should be able to use the following XPath expression :

```
//Employee[name/@lang='en']
```

The XPath return `Employee` element where the corresponding child `name` has attribute `lang` equals `"en"`. Or in case `name` may not be direct child of `Employee`, you can use the following expression instead :

```
//Employee[.//name/@lang='en']
```

Notice the `.` before `//` which indicate that the expression inside the predicate (`[]`) is relative to current `Employee` context.

Comment: @beni don't forget [to accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it solved the problem in question